# python: interact with the session in cgi scripts

Tags: python, session, cgi

Can python cgi scripts write and read data to the session? If so how? Is there a high-level API or must I roll my own classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no "*session*" on `cgi`. You must roll your own session handling code if you're using raw `cgi`.

Basically, sessions work by creating a unique cookie number and sending it on a response header to the client, and then checking for this cookie on every connection. Store the session data somewhere on the server (memory, database, disk) and use the cookie number as a key to retrieve it on every request made by the client.

However `cgi` is not how you develop applications for the web in python. Use [`wsgi`](http://wsgi.org/). Use a web framework.

Here's a quick example using [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org/). `cherrypy.tools.sessions` is a cherrypy tool that handles cookie setting/retrieving and association with data automatically:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloSessionWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.tools.sessions()
    def index(self):
        if 'data' in cherrypy.session:
            return "You have a cookie! It says: %r" % cherrypy.session['data']
        else:
            return "You don't have a cookie. <a href='getcookie'>Get one</a>."
    index.exposed = True

    @cherrypy.tools.sessions()
    def getcookie(self):
        cherrypy.session['data'] = 'Hello World'
        return "Done. Please <a href='..'>return</a> to see it"
    getcookie.exposed = True

application = cherrypy.tree.mount(HelloSessionWorld(), '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(application)
```

Note that this code is a `wsgi` application, in the sense that you can publish it to any `wsgi`-enabled web server (apache has [`mod_wsgi`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi)). Also, cherrypy has its own `wsgi` server, so you can just run the code with python and it will start serving on [`http://localhost:8080/`](http://localhost:8080/)

Comment: +1 for WSGI... of course in the meantime you can deploy WSGI over CGI. In fact it can be a good idea, as the single-process-run-once scheme means you don't have to worry about module reloading issues on a dev server.

Answer (score 1):

My 'low-cost' web hosting plan don't permit use **wsgi**. The 'mod_wsgi' apache module can't be used because is a shared apache server. I am developing my own class.

To not start from zero, I am experimenting the implementation of a session class available in this site: http://cgi.tutorial.codepoint.net/a-session-class