# What modules ought I to consider in Python if I wish to use CGI sessions?

Tags: python, session

Given that I know no web frameworks in Python and would like to keep it Very Simple at the moment (as I am Very Stupid), for what is a prototype of sketchy longevity, are there any streamlined, simple, "batteries-included" modules for this?  (It is also too early in my Python career to evaluate frameworks, select one, and learn it.)  I see a module named "Cookie," which could serve as a foundation, but nothing session-specific.

I'm familiar with the basic session concepts, having used them in classic ASP and gotten into the nuts-and-bolts of them in Perl, but I am not seeing a lot for Python.  Beaker looks interesting, but then the documentation seems to require middleware with WSGI and I'm back to the frameworks problem.

I've found an old recipe on ActiveState for sessions, which could obviously use some buffing up.  The information being held is not anything anyone would mind having been grabbed, so while I am normally quite security conscious, I would be willing to be a little bit more lax with this prototype.

Or is this a "roll-your-own" problem?

I will be using Python 2.6 on IIS 7.0.

Comment: If you dont mind I am quite curious as to the reasons for using python with IIS 7.0.  I'm not saying it is a good/bad idea, just out of curiosity.

Comment: Because that's what I have to work with.  The decision of operating system is both political and beyond my control.  And I don't fancy trying to shoehorn Apache onto a Windows box, and then try to refresh my very dim Apache skills all for the sake of ... well, I'm not sure what.  So IIS 7.0 it is.

Comment: Apache installs smoothly and simply onto Windows.

Comment: And again, I know IIS much better than I know Apache.  IIS is already installed on the target server.  The target website is already running under IIS.  It was transitioned to that and away from Apache for mostly political and some technical reasons.  I am not going to install Apache simply for the Greater Glory of Open Source.

Comment: @MetaHyperBolic: I would suggest that Apache is simpler than IIS.  The greater glory of blah-blah isn't the issue.  The issue is simply *simpler*.  Apache is simpler.  It does less.  Making it handle mod_wsgi very, very cleanly and simply.

Comment: Great.  But I don't know Apache all that well.  I know IIS very well.  So Apache is not more simple for me.  And I am not migrating everything back to Apache, because that is also more work.  All of these things make Apache less simple for me.  Apache provides for me absolutely zero benefit in this scenario.  No bonus at all.  And it's not even relevant to my problem.  Please leave your LAMP agenda at the door.

Comment: @MetaHyperBolic: Why do you keep harping on the LAMP "agenda" and the "Greater Glory of blah-blah".  It's simpler.  The fact that it doesn't work for you is a simple fact.  Not politics.  Fact.  Please stop reading politics into something that's factual.  It's simpler.  You have good reasons for not using it.  Leave it at the facts, please.

Comment: I'd leave alone if everyone else would leave it alone.  Unfortunately, there's a long history in the computing subculture of "If I don't know the answer, the question and the person asking it must be questioned."  Specifically, nobody seems to know of any modules, so instead it's "why did you pick IIS?"  Despite the fact that it is completely irrelevant to the question at hand, someone must bring up the all-important question of Why This Isn't Open Source All The Way.

Comment: @MetaHyperBolic could you accept an answer or specifiy if you need more information?

Answer (score 3):

I think the [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) (web framework) is easy enough for you. I think it is the simplest approach of making a website or webservice. It will be also **easier**, than to understand Cookie or the other modules of python related to web-things.

You can start a session, by just typing:

```
session.your_session_name = "blabla" # or whatever you want to store
```

To make a cookie, just look [here](http://www.web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/157).

In web2py you don't have to configure anything. Just download it and start web2py.py. (you must have python 2.6 < installed.) You can also find some [examples](http://www.web2py.com/examples/default/examples) and a [web-slide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16085263/web2py-slides-version-1644).

The Python [Cookie module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/cookie.html) does nothing more than to hold some values in a dictonary-like object, but I think you have to store it yourself on your harddisk.

Comment: It's a framework, not a module, which is sad.  It seems to be built on top of CherryPy.  And it's got an Admin Interface, so that's something else to fuss over, even sadder.  And the stuff on the home page mentions integration with Twitter -- that's when I reach for my revolver.

Comment: yes it's a bit fussy, but what do you want to made with just a cookie module? And btw. response.cookies['name'] of web2py is built on pythons SimpleCookie of the Cookie module.

Comment: It is not built on top of cherrypy. It only uses the cherrypy web server if you do not have a better web server. If you have Apache+mod_wsgi for example it does not uses any cherrypy code.

Comment: Minor correction to the original post. Sessions are always on unless disabled. In the following code:

    session.your_session_name = "blabla"

"your_session_name" is not your session name. It would be a variable you are storing the session with name "your_session_name". For example:

    session.your_variable = "bla"
    session.your_other_variable = "blablabla"

Comment: @MetaHyperbolic. The admin interface is an app built on web2py that ships with web2py, that can be removed, and it is not needed fr web2py to work. That admin interface uses twitter for notification of news. The underlying libraries are just python modules (like the DAL or the template engine or the form generation) which you can access from the shell. It is true that the web2py modules have a lot of interdependence so if you only need sessions you should consider lighter.

Answer (score 0):

[CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) is worth looking into.  Yes it is a framework, and yes it requires WSGI, but it is extremely lightweight compared to other more robust alternatives.

There is another question that was answered on SO that gives a [brief example on how to manage sessions with CherryPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554250/python-interact-with-the-session-in-cgi-scripts/1554303#1554303).  As you can see it makes it very easy to get up and running quickly.

Lastly, [here is a little document](http://www.aminus.net/wiki/ASPGateway) about setting up IIS for use with CherryPy.

Answer (score 0):

WSGI is not a framework, nor does it require that you choose one -- it's THE standard way to run any Python web app framework on any Python-supporting web server, including a CGI one.  If you have a WSGI application named `app`, and want to run it on CGI, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html?highlight=wsgi#wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler) and use `wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)`, as the docs say.

So, you can perfectly well use [Beaker](http://beaker.groovie.org/) via WSGI (on top of CGI) -- e.g., take the example in Beaker's [docs](http://beaker.groovie.org/sessions.html#using) and just add (the needed imports and) the `run` call above (using the `wsgi_app` object that example constructs, plus of course a `session.save` and as well needed as, again, the Beaker docs explain right afterwards).

Rich or heavy frameworks have their place but so do lightweight, flexible components like Beaker -- and WSGI middleware is a great way to leverage such components without requiring any "framework-y" arrangements, just good old WSGI (on top of CGI or anything else).

BTW, the best way to run WSGI on IIS might be [isapi-wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/) (I can only say "might" because I have no IIS installation on which to test it;-).  But as long as you code to WSGI (with any framework or with none at all), that will only be an optimization -- your application won't change (net of what handler's `run` or equivalent method you need to call;-) whether it's running on CGI, IIS via ISAPI, Google App Engine, or any other server-and-interface-thereto combination

Comment: It's still not relevant.  I'm looking for Python modules.  Not frameworks, not other things I have to layer in.  These constraints were solvable in Perl, simply by using the CGI::Session module, which is unlovely but functional.

If the answer is "I do not know of Python modules which do this; you must roll your own" that's perfectly okay to say.

Comment: @Meta, wsgiref is a module, beaker.middleware is a module, isapi-wsgi -- they're not frameworks, and what you call "layering in" (by which I assume you mean decorators and other higher-order functions) is simply one of the ways to use a module in Python, no more and no less than calling functions from it or inheriting from its classes -- Python's apt to use functional idioms (such as HOFs, genexps and other iterators, etc) no less than procedural or OOP ones (Session is not "functional" in the paradigm sense, of course;-). Tragic that you just refuse to see this, really.

Comment: It's tragic that you fail to understand what I am asking.  You're suggesting I install something else (isapi-wsgi). I'm just looking for a module.  Something which does not require installing frameworks, or .exes, or stuff that sits in the ISAPI layer.  You're trying to sell me on an SUV when I'm looking for a moped.  If you don't have mopeds, that's completely okay, I will not be upset.  

Perl could do this with CGI::Session.  No ISAPI layer stuff, no frameworks.  It was just a module.  If Python does not have an analogous module, that's an acceptable outcome.  That appears to be the case.

Comment: @Meta, read my response carefully again: isapi-wsgi is a "by the way" (you **know** what BTW stands for, do you?) in the fourth paragraph (first sentence only: the rest of the paragraph explains that it doesn't really matter except as an optimization!). The first three paragraphs explain how you run a wsgi app (which is just a function you write to respect certain conventions) on top of CGI with the Python standard library -- no installing frameworks, no exes, no stuff that sits in the ISAPI layer. Your rant and your inability to read plain English are truly tragic!